# issue retrieving child input type. currently returning as 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, forms, input

so the best way for you to understand what I am trying to achieve is to view this demo:
[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6jDR/4/).

the problem is that the type being returned is 'undefined' rather that 'text'.

Can anybody please explain why this happening?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change your HTML, this code is working :

```
$(".question").each(function(){
        var type = $('input[type != "hidden"]',this).attr("type");
        alert(type);
});

// Or

$(".question").each(function(){
        var type = $(this).find('input[type != "hidden"]').attr("type");
        alert(type);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what your code is doing:

```
// for each '.question' element
$(".question").each(function() { 
    // find the 'input' children which are not 'type=hidden'
    var children = $(this).children('input[type != "hidden"]');
    // get the type
    var type = children.attr('type');
}
```

You have two `question` elements. The first one contains no elements matching the children selector (the `text` input is not a direct child as it is nested in `h3`), so you have an empty array.

In the first iteration of `each`, you are trying to read `attr('type')` from an empty array, which is giving you `undefined`.

In the second iteration of `each`, you are trying to read `attr('type')` from an array with more than one element.

I presume what you are trying to do is something more along the lines of...

```
$(".question").each(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type != "hidden"]').each(function() {
         alert($(this).attr("type"));
    });   
});
```

Note that `find` seaches through **all** children, not just the immediate children as `children` does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, that you try to find a  non-hidden input element - child in the  ".question" div.

But your function doesn't pickup the grand-child element , and in this case  is that one . that's why you get back "undefined" response.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the input `type=text` is inside an `h3`:

```
<h3>The binary language consists of <input type='text' name='response[4][answer]'>digit(s).</h3>
```

Fix your HTML to:

```
<h3>The binary language consists of </h3><input type='text' name='response[4][answer]'>digit(s).
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Z6jDR/12/